# How to scrape data from a web graph into R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrape

The website TRAC Immigration has data on the number of ICE deportations by month and year for each city in Texas. I would like to download this data into R, but there is not a data file available. I think this means I need to scrape the data, but I don't know how to do so. Here is the website: [TRAC Immigration](https://trac.syr.edu/phptools/immigration/remove/)

There is a table for each city that displays the total number of deportations over the 19 year period but not by month and year.

[image: Table with number of deportation by county]

However, there is a graph for each city that displays the number of deportations by month and year. This information is only displayed when you hover your cursor over each bar of the graph.

[image: Graph with number of deportations by county by month and year]

Please let me know if you have any ideas about how I could scrape the data from the graph for each city into R. I would eventually like to have the number of deportations be a variable in a dataset.

Comment: The data is stored as a JSON file.  One can use this to access the data: `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://trac.syr.edu/phptools/immigration/remove/graph.php?stat=count&timescale=fymon&depart_state=2&timeunit=number")`

Comment: @Dave2e How would you modify that code to get the number of deportations by month and year for a specific city departed from in Texas (e.g., "LAREDO, TX, POE)?

Answer (score 2):

@Dave2e did the hard work, but here's a way of using what he found to get the different cities. You could replace `depart_state` with `depart_city`.  Now, you don't know which cities are which, so you can use some brute force to get all of them.  I was able to get the data for 397 cities in a few minutes:

```
out <- NULL
for(i in 1:397){
url <- glue::glue("https://trac.syr.edu/phptools/immigration/remove/graph.php?stat=count&timescale=fymon&depart_city={i}&timeunit=number")
j <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
tm <- j$timeline
tm$city <- j$title
out <- rbind(out, tm)
}
out %>% dplyr::filter(city == "LAREDO, TX, POE")
```